# Vertical line div disappears if containing element is auto sized

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap, with the following html:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-md" align="center">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto h-100 d-none d-md-flex">
            <div class="vertical_divider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md" align="center">
            <a href="/users/signup/"><div class="signup_button"><p>Signup</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following relevant css:

```
.page_content {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 75vh; #Changing this to 'auto' makes the vertical divider disappear
    max-height: 75vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.vertical_divider {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border: none;
    border-right: 3px solid $bordercolour;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/176561/

This makes a div that is always 75% of the viewport height, regardless of its content. This works perfectly.

I want to modify it so that the div is only as big as its contents, up to a maximum of 75vh. If the content is bigger than that, the overflow should scroll within the div. I've done this by changing the `height` attribute of the `page_content` class to `auto`. This works, except that it makes the central orange line disappear (this happens in the fiddle too, if you change the setting).

Why does this happen? `h-100` should make the column containing the vertical divider 100% of the row, and yet it doesn't. I've tried making various styles `!important`, but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why does this happen?*

Because a percentage height only works when the parent element has a set height, with the exception of the `html` tag. When you set `.page_content` height to `auto`, there is no longer a set height on the parent element of the divider, and thus a percentage height does nothing.

To make it work you either need to ensure that the parent element chain all the way until `html` has a set height (i.e. not `auto`). Or as an alternative solution, if your middle column has no other purpose than the divider line, the whole column is kind of pointless since you can just create the line as a CSS border of one of the two other columns.